# Activation Error on Active Reports 7

Tags: report, activereports, componentone

[Active Reports license Activation Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ScDF.png)

I have a problem activating my Active Reports 7, We have 3 users sharing on the license but one already uninstalled the software to give way for another one. Do you have any idea what is the proper way to give license space to other users in Active Reports 7. And Licensing Manager?

Comment: If one deactivated the license, then the other user should be able to activate it. You should contact the ActiveReports sales team directly.

Comment: you should know that AR is licensed per developer.  why would you be sharing the license among 3 users?